# what if I want to create a inner function which will access the outer scope variable, but it can't be a closure? is it possible?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I want to understand that if I have use case, which is inner Function needs to access the outer scope variable but it can't be closure(it can't remember the value of a variable even if outer function finishes it's execution)

I'm not able to get the idea to create one

check the following scala code

```
object ExternalVariableExample extends App {

  // Outer function
  def outerFunction(): Int => Int = {
    // External variable
    var outerVariable = 0

    // Inner function (closure) accessing the external variable
    (x: Int) => {
      outerVariable += x
      outerVariable
    }
  }

  // Create a closure
  val closure = outerFunction()

  // Call closure multiple times
  val result1 = closure(5)  // Output: 5 (outerVariable = 0 + 5)
  val result2 = closure(3)  // Output: 8 (outerVariable = 5 + 3)

  // Print results
  println(s"Result 1: $result1")
  println(s"Result 2: $result2")
}
```

when `val result1 = closure(5)` completes its execution, `outerVariable` value become `5(0 + 5)`, becuase of closure when `val result2 = closure(3)` executing, `outerVariable` value still `5`, so it becomes `8(5 + 3)`.

Now my need is, I have inner function, in that I needed to access the outer scope variable, but when I'm calling multiple times with different values, whatever the outer scope variable that I'm accessing it shouldn't remember the previous call value. It should reset to declared value which is `outerVariable = 0`.

I hope my ask is valid, if not apologies in advance.

Comment: What specifically should differ this function from a closure and why?

Comment: Inner function can't remember the outer scope variable after the outer function finishes its execution. I'm learning scala so I want to understand a possible scenario of such a situation.

Comment: It's not clear for me what is exactly the issue you are detailing in your question. Are you trying to mimic some strategy that is possible in another language and you can't find out how to do it? If that is the case share a working example in the other stack. Also show what you have in scala that is not working

Comment: I edited my question in detailed way. I hope that clarifies you what I'm asking @Gastón Schabas

Comment: Move the `outerVariable` inside the inner function? Also, TBH, I am surprised the external variable remains alive, this all seems to very bad design, with memory leaks and race conditions. - I would advise trying to solve your problem without mutability.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing here

```scala
// Outer function
def outerFunction(): Int => Int = {
  // External variable
  var outerVariable = 0

  // Inner function (closure) accessing the external variable
  (x: Int) => {
    outerVariable += x
    outerVariable
  }
}

val closure = outerFunction()
val result1 = closure(5) // Output: 5 (outerVariable = 0 + 5)
val result2 = closure(3) // Output: 8 (outerVariable = 5 + 3)
```

it's the same if you do something like

```scala
class OuterClass {

  private var outerVariable: Int = 0

  def innerFunction(x: Int) = {
    outerVariable += x
    outerVariable
  }
}

val outerClass = new OuterClass()
val result1 = outerClass.innerFunction(5)
val result2 = outerClass.innerFunction(3)
```

Not sure what is exactly your use case, but looks like you are trying to get the same value for the same inputs. That's is called [pure function](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/fp-pure-functions.html)

> - A function `f` is pure if, given the same input x, it always returns the same output `f(x)`
> - The function’s output depends only on its input variables and its implementation
> - It only computes the output and does not modify the world around it

In that case you could do something like

```scala
def ComposableFunction: Int => Int => Int = {
  (outer: Int) => {
    (inner: Int) => {
      outer + inner
    }
  }
}

val composableFunction: Int => Int = ComposableFunction(0)
val result1: Int = composableFunction(5)
val result2: Int = composableFunction(3)
```

This will print

```
Result 1: 5
Result 2: 3
```

As you can see, I changed the result type of the function. Instead of returning a function of `Int => Int`, now I'm returning a `Int => Int => Int`.

In the first call I'm calling `ComposableFunction` with `0` as a parameter. This returns a `Int => Int`

```scala
val composableFunction: Int => Int = ComposableFunction(0)
```

The `0` value lives inside `composableFunction` and each time I call that higher order function passing different values as parameter, it will always apply the logic using that `0` and it will not change, unless I call the function `ComposableFunction(anotherValue)` and save it to a new `val`

```scala
val composableFunction3 = ComposableFunction(3)
val result1 = composableFunction3(5)
val result2 = composableFunction3(8)
```

and the result will be

```
Result 1: 8
Result 2: 11
```

---

All this concepts comes from the [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) paradigm.

The following articles might help to understand better how to apply this concepts

- [Baeldung - function composition](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/function-composition)
- [Baeldung - Introduction to Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/functional-programming)

There is also a good course in coursera about functional programming

- [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-functional-programming?specialization=scala)
- [Functional Program Design in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/learn/scala-functional-program-design?specialization=scala)